# How to perforate in a import 3ds object?

Tags: graphics

now i want to drill a hole in the 3ds object i import,and if  the mesh of the 3ds object within the hole, this part mesh will be delete,that mean if the surface of the object within the hole, this part will be delete,can anyone give me some suggestions?

that is :

first i import a 3ds format file,then i use a cylinder to penetrate it,So everything

belong to this 3ds file but within my cyLinder will be deleted,

for example if this 3ds file is a cube,to perforate a hole on it,the result will be a cube whose front face and back face all add a circle,
am i make the problem clear?

Thanks.
Good luck.

---

if i should calculate the node within the cylinder ?i don't not know the structure of the 3ds file.

---

it seems that i should calculate the difference of 3ds and a cylinder?
that mean i should subtract the cylinder,delete the node within the cylinder ?

am i right?

THanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify how this is a programming question. And yeah, clarifiy ALOT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a programming website then the answer is... [BSP Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning).